# WinINET and PHP php://input POST read

Tags: php, wininet

I have a weird problem. I want to upload some data with WinInet to a PHP script.

When I upload the data at once with HttpSendRequest(), then PHP reads the uploaded data correctly, e.g.

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

When I upload the data in parts with HttpSendRequestEx() and InternetWriteFile() , then the same data is uploaded, but PHP fails to read the input (empty).

What could be wrong?
Is the PHP script "called" before the entire data is uploaded?
If so, how do I get the data?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, Content-Length header was missing.